# Find all “*.wav” files that created yesterday on linux host with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, file-conversion

There is so many .wav files and create alot of these files everyday on Linux Host. I want to find all wav files that created yesterday ( a day ago when script run )on subdirectories and convert them to mp3 format with python script. I run os.walk ( path ) for finding '.wav' files but can not check that they was create yesterday.

```
for root, dir, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.wav'):
            wav = root + '/' + str(file)
            cmd = 'lame --preset insane %s' % wav
            subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

Your answers can help alot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about using `find` with its `mtime/ctime` options? Or does it *have* to be in Python? It seems to me that, since your Python is calling an external `lame` process to do the grunt work, you may as well just bypass Python altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `os` offers, as [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) says three function regarding handling of times of files:

- `os.path.getatime(path)` - time of last access to *path*
- `os.path.getmtime(path)` - time of last modification of *path*
- `os.path.getctime(path)` - for Unix time of the last metadata change of *path*

None is said to give creation time for Unix system, but maybe one of them will prove good enough for your purposes? (I suggest giving a try `getmtime` if you do not alter your `*.wav` files after they are created)

All these functions returns time in seconds since start of epoch. You can use `time`'s module `time` to get "now" in seconds since start of epoch, that is:

```
import time
now = time.time()
```

And then compare it to time which you get from file for example:

```
import os
import time
now = time.time()
mtime = os.path.getmtime('path/to/some/file.wav')
if (mtime + 24*60*60) >= now:
    print('File was altered during last 24 hours')
```

Comment: if i use  

if (mtime + 24*60*60) >= now:

i found all wav files that created yesterday and all day before. i Want to  search that files created yesterday